# Calculate days between 2 dates automatically

Tags: odoo-10

In odoo 10, I'd like to have a computed field that calculates every day difference between the current date and another date:
This is my code:

Python :

```py
days_number = fields.Integer('Days remaining', compute='_compute_remaining_days', store=True)
@api.depends('maturity_date')
def _compute_remaining_days(self):
    current_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
    date1 = False
    if self.maturity_date:
        date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.maturity_date, "%Y-%m-%d")

    date2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(current_date), "%Y-%m-%d")
    date3 = date1 - date2
    date = int(date3.days)
    self.days_number = date
```

XML:

```xml
 <record id="ir_cron_remain_days" model="ir.cron">
    <field name="name">Remaining Days</field>
    <field eval="True" name="active"/>
    <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root"/>
    <field name="interval_number">1</field>
    <field name="interval_type">days</field>
    <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
    <field eval="False" name="doall"/>
    <field name="model">tresorerie_test.account.payment.maturity</field>
    <field name="function">_compute_remaining_days</field>
    <field name="args">()</field>
</record>
```

The problem that the field doesn't get the value automatically.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You need to use [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) to express the difference between two dates

Comment: I would remove the compute method from the field, the automatic function should update the field. The compute method on a field is executed each time the value is needed

Answer (score 1):

- If you have given your 'days_number' field in xml view then remove
  store=True it will work as desired.
- There no need to type cast in integer you already getting an integer

  `start = date(2018,04,03)
  end = date(2018,04,10)
  ans = end - start
  print ans.days`

Answer (score 0):

If we have 2 dates (start_date, end_date) and we want to calculate the number of days between these dates, we can do it as in the function below:

```
def calculate_days_between_dates(self):
    diff_date = self.end_date - self.start_date
    float_days = diff_date.days + float(diff_date.seconds)/ 86400
    days_number = int(float_days)

    return days_number
```